# Main module field cannot be resolved after installing @apollo/client

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, bundler, apollo-client

I'm running into an error after installing Apollo when trying to run my React Native Expo app. I've tried deleting node-modules and re-installing, resetting cache, restarting computer, and still no luck.

> Android Bundling failed 456ms
> While trying to resolve module `@apollo/client` from file >`/mnt/c/Users/14044/Desktop/Coding/divii/client/App.tsx`, the package >`/mnt/c/Users/14044/Desktop/Coding/divii/client/node_modules/@apollo/client/package.json` >was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that >could not be resolved >(`/mnt/c/Users/14044/Desktop/Coding/divii/client/node_modules/@apollo/client/main.cjs`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

> - /mnt/c/Users/14044/Desktop/Coding/divii/client/node_modules/@apollo/client/main.cjs(.native|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
> - /mnt/c/Users/14044/Desktop/Coding/divii/client/node_modules/@apollo/client/main.cjs/index(.native|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)

Answer (score 33):

This is a conflict between @apollo/client v3.5.4 and RN metro bundler.

As a workaround until this issue is resolved, you can configure Metro by creating a **metro.config.js** file in the root of your React Native project with following content:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");
const { resolver: defaultResolver } = getDefaultConfig.getDefaultValues();
exports.resolver = {
  ...defaultResolver,
  sourceExts: [
    ...defaultResolver.sourceExts,
    "cjs",
  ],
};
```

This workaround was posted on Apollo Github Releases page
[here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/releases/tag/v3.5.4).

Comment: doesnt solve the problem

Comment: @LukAron it has solved this problem for me... it did absolutely nothing to you? did not even changed the error?

Comment: It didn't work for me at first, I changed `metro.config.js` and tried on my emulator. Same error. But then I closed metro and re-opened and it worked!

Answer (score 9):

This is an issue with the latest version of `Apollo Client` (3.5.0 and up) and the way `Metro bundler` works. You need to configure Metro to understand the `.cjs` files used in `@apollo/client` by creating a `metro.config.js` in the root folder of your project.

Here is the link to a solution on the `Apollo` releases [page](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/releases/tag/v3.5.4).

I tried the solution, it didn't work, the error was solved, but the build broke for other packages in the project, so I tried a similar but different approach

Here is my `metro.config.js`

```
const {getDefaultConfig} = require('metro-config');

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: {sourceExts},
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      getTransformOptions: async () => ({
        transform: {
          experimentalImportSupport: false,
          inlineRequires: true,
        },
      }),
    },
    resolver: {
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'cjs'],
    },
  };
})();
```

Answer (score 8):

Try downgrading to `@apollo/client` `3.4.16`.  I just did a round of package updates and the `3.5.4` broke my build as well.  I'm using the downgraded package with a downgraded version of `graphql` lib as well -- `15.7.2`.

Those are the last versions that worked for me with the current version of Expo / RN.

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: works,  but cannot be used together with https://stackoverflow.com/a/70076278/10189759

Comment: Nice! any idea what is actually causing this problem?

Comment: This was the trick.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone using Expo and the new Apollo Client, you should update your `metro.config.js` to look like this:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('@expo/metro-config');

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

defaultConfig.resolver.sourceExts.push('cjs');

module.exports = defaultConfig;
```

It's important to make sure you use the expo metro config defaults otherwise eas will complain at build time.

Comment: Thank you. This seemed to work best for me in an expo bare app.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue in a Vanilla/Bare React Native Project with Apollo Client 3.5.8

The project already had the default metro.config.js

I just modified it to the following code :

```
const {getDefaultConfig} = require('metro-config');
const {resolver: defaultResolver} = getDefaultConfig.getDefaultValues();

module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
  },
  resolver: {
    ...defaultResolver,
    sourceExts: [...defaultResolver.sourceExts, 'cjs'],
  },
};
```

With this change the issue was resolved